# How can I have [Fragile] Notes?

Tags: beamer, presentations, easylist

I want to use Easylist to make dot points in my slide notes.
Easylist would be great for that.

So I used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] {What is Domain Adaptation?} 
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]   
        @ \emph{Problem Domain:} An area expertise needed to solve a particular problem
        @@ Neural nets work within a problem domain
        @ What if we could transfer knowledge from one problem domain to another
        @ \emph{Source Domain:} the domain we are transferring ideas from
        @ \emph{Target Domain:} the domain we actually want to solve
    \end{easylist}
    \note{\begin{easylist}[itemize] 
            @ Primates Transfer Knowledge %\footfullcite{braun2010structure}
            @@ After solving one Food box puzzle
            @@ Are much better as solving other food box puzzle that is completely different    
            @ \emph{Source Domain:} Basket Ball
            @ \emph{Target Domain:} Soccer
            @ This does actually work for soccer and basketball 
            %\footfullcite{lopez2009role}
        \end{easylist}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see this worked fine for the mainframe, but didn't work in the handout frame.
How can I make it work in the handout frame?

[image: slides]

I believe the way to do this is to redefine the beamer template for a `note page`,
to be built around a `fragile` frame rather than a normal one.

Comment: `easylist` cannot be used in the argument to a command and the `frame` text *is* the argument to a command, unless the `fragile` option is used. However, `fragile` has effect only in presentation mode.

Comment: and the `\note` command won't take a fragile optional argument.
Ergo a \renewcommand on `\note` is needed.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\usepackage{easylist}`, enclosing the snippet in a `document` environment, I get nothing similar to your first picture. Please, make a full MWE showing the issue.

Comment: egreg: You need to use \usepackage[at]{easylist}, MWE coming soon.
Other than that is is just a style template . I will even put in a new picture to not confuse if you really want

Comment: `easylist` can't go in the argument to another command. So it can't go as argument to `\note`, no matter whether you use `fragile` or not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the actual problem of the OP stems from the impossibility to use an `easylist` as another macro's argument, as pointed by egreg.